# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied error - can log in directly to mysql fine but not from web page

Tags: php, mysql

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I am just running localhost on my own computer. Have not run into this error before.
I am able to log in directly to mysql with both root and the user in question.
Via php connection I can log in to the web page successfully if I use the root user credentials but if I switch them to the regular user I get that error message.

I have reviewed similar threads with this error but not found specific answer that will work for me.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think I had something similar in the past and I discovered that both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are the host names that can be used in the MySQL users table. I expect it depends how the reverse lookup is done by the driver. Don't forget to flush the privileges after changing or adding the MySQL user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if both users are present in `mysql.user` and have `localhost` assigned as allowed `host`:

```
select user, host from mysql.user where user in ('root', 'username');
+----------+-----------+
| user     | host      |
+----------+-----------+
| root     | localhost |
| username | localhost |
+----------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If that is the case check the privileges for `username@localhost`:

```
show grants for username@localhost;
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for username@localhost                              |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost'               |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydb`.* TO 'username'@'localhost' |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Make sure that your database (in this example `mydb`) is in the list.

Next you could check if the passwords that you try to log in with from your app and on the commandline are the same.

```
mysql -u username -h localhost -p <password-copied-from-php-code>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I checked everything and the only thing I could think of was having an exclamation point in the password. I updated the password without one and it worked fine now. Oddly enough I have one in my root password and it worked fine. Oh well at least I have it working.

Comment: That's odd, in my experience exclamation marks in mysql passwords should never be problem. But I'm glad to hear that it's working now!